# Reprojection from EPSG:4167 to EPSG:2193

Tags: fme-form, epsg

I have PostgreSQL database with defined EPSG:2193.
WMS service that I need to use and upload data from it is in EPSG:4167.

https://data.linz.govt.nz/layer/105689-nz-addresses/

https://data.linz.govt.nz/services;key=9732cee676774ee5a2c19d5dc310392e/wfs/layer-105689/?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities

If I apply Projector transformer in FME reprojecting data into EPSG:2193 - I am getting data reprojected but Translation Log has the following message:

> NOT changing coordinate system of reader identified by keyword 'MITAB_1' from 'EPSG:4167' to 'LL-NZGD2000' -- mapping file setting of 'EPSG:4167' overrides coordinate system 'LL-NZGD2000' read from file'

When compare output data is has a shift about 4cm.

I am confused by FME message, not sure if everything is fine. Could you advise?

Comment: From the message it seems like you set the projection in one location but the reader projection is not changed and overriddes what you set. I found this from FME site - https://community.safe.com/s/article/using-coordinate-systems-within-fme